# PHP Mysql - create previous and next link from current customer

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page listing customers:

```
/customers/
```

The order of customers on this page is not sequential:

```
1st: ID 111
2nd: ID 567
3rd: ID 345
etc
```

That's because the SQL query lets the user select the customer order based on first name, last name, or nickname.

```
"SELECT customer_id FROM customers WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY " . $customer_order
```

So when I am on the 2nd customer in my example above:

```
/customer/567/
```

So my problem is I want to display a previous and next button like this, but can't figure out how:

```
<a href="111">Prev</a>
<a href="567">Current</a>
<a href="345">Next</a>
```

I managed to get the Previous link working in a while loop but it's ugly. I tried using current(), prev(), and next() but failed.

Most solutions I've seen on StackOverflow are to do with sequential IDs where they either -1 or 1 the current ID, or they "LIMIT 1" in the query which I'm fairly sure doesn't work in my situation after testing this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Pass the current customer's ID to next/prev function and seek next one in db.

In your way, you have to do 3 queries for each record. In my way you have to do only one and max 2 if u click prev or next button

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a row number to your query and use that row number to identify previous and next records:

```
SELECT (@row_number := @row_number + 1) AS row_number, customer_id 
FROM customers, (SELECT @row_number := 0) AS rn
WHERE status = 1 
ORDER BY firstname
```

If you have the row number for current customer, find the next/previous records using the main query as a sub-query:

```
SELECT customer_id AS next_id
FROM 
(
    SELECT (@row_number := @row_number + 1) AS row_number, customer_id 
    FROM customers, (SELECT @row_number := 0) AS rn
    WHERE status = 1 
    ORDER BY firstname
) ordered_customers
WHERE ordered_customers.row_number = :current_row_number + 1
```

If you just have the current id:

```
SELECT customer_id AS next_id
FROM 
(
    SELECT (@row_number := @row_number + 1) AS row_number, customer_id 
    FROM customers, (SELECT @row_number := 0) AS rn
    WHERE status = 1 
    ORDER BY firstname
) ordered_customers
WHERE ordered_customers.row_number = 1 + ( 
    SELECT row_number 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT (@row_number2 := @row_number2 + 1) AS row_number, customer_id 
        FROM customers, (SELECT @row_number2 := 0) AS rn
        WHERE status = 1 
        ORDER BY firstname
    ) ordered_customers2
    WHERE ordered_customers2.id = :current_id
)
```